# Search for a product in Amazon using amazon api

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am using amazon api for getting details of a product whether it exists or not. I have created Access Key ID, Secret Access Key & Associate ID. I called this to get the details

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=**KEY**&AssociateTag=**TAG**&Operation=ItemSearch&Keywords=the%20hunger%20games&SearchIndex=Books&Timestamp=2016-10-07T12:18:26Z&Signature=Signature
```

but I am getting

**"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details**"

What should I do to get rid of this issue.? How to get signature?
Also I would like to know whether I could post a product with amazon api ?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't comment on your post as I'm still low on reputation, anyway it says that signature they have calculated doesn't match with yours .. this can happen

- When your API key and Secret Access Key doesn't match with their
  system
- The signature for that particular timestamp may be expired

Try requesting a new API and secret key from their service

Comment: But the credentials i got from their console.. I rechecked twice and the credentals was correct... ;(

Comment: How did you generated that signature key value?

Comment: I did nt get a signature key...How to get it?

Comment: @AkhilGopan this url part `&Signature=**Signature**` how is it generated? what is the nodejs module that you're using?

Comment: https://github.com/dmcquay/node-apac
 And is there any module for uploading produts to amazon via its API ?

Comment: can you post your code somewhere? perhaps to [kopy.io](http://kopy.io)?